# Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "lstm_param"

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to run the LRCN example from Jeff Donahue's recurrent-rebase-cleanup branch of Caffe. I have installed the latest caffe version from the master branch. According to my knowledge Caffe now supports LSTM layers. But when I run the solver I get this error. Is the name of the field wrong? If so then what is the correct field name and how can I find caffe layer parameter & field names for future use?

I also tried running with the parameter name as `recurrent_param` but still get the same error.

Comment: Check `caffe.proto` file and then navigate to the LSTM layer. You will find all the parameters and their default values for the LSTM layer listed there.

Comment: The problem is not with the parameter. It's with the name of the field. Is the name lstm_param or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `"LSTM"` layer from the latest "master" branch, you need to use `recurrent_param` **instead** of `lstm_param`.
For more information see [caffe.help](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/lstm.html).

---

Generally speaking, if you are trying to run a model build in a specific branch of caffe, you should build and use caffe of that specific branch as layer names/parameters may vary across branches (as it seems to be the case here)

Comment: I tried with recurrent_param too but I get the same error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @TheBaus then you have lstm_param somewhere else in the fikr

Comment: Could you please take a look at my prototxt file: http://pastebin.com/USj4Us3N    and the solver file: http://pastebin.com/YWqVDwuW it would really help me a lot

Comment: please provide the log @TheBaus

Comment: @TheBaus you have a **different** error: caffe does not recognize `recurrent_param`. please make sure you have it defined in your [`$CAFFE_ROOT/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L395) file. Have you re-comlied your caffe after pulling recent master branch?